# SIGSEGV when using interfaces

Tags: interface, segmentation-fault, fpc

Please take a look at the following Free Pascal program.

```
type
  IMyInterface = interface
  end;

  TMyClass = class(TInterfacedObject, IMyInterface)
  end;

var
  MyInstance: TMyClass;

procedure DoSomething(MyParameter: IMyInterface);
begin
end;

begin
  MyInstance := TMyClass.Create;

  DoSomething(MyInstance);

  MyInstance.Free;
end.
```

The program crashes during the access to the destructor with a SIGSEGV when started from within the IDE (compiled with debug information). Why? It works when I use `TInterfacedObject`, `TObject`, or `TMyClass` as parameter type. It even works when I use the `const` keyword for said parameter. Can anyone explain this behavior? With a quick sideways glance to Java I would expect this to work.

Compiled with FreePascalCompiler 2.6.4, executed under Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot speak for FPC, but with Delphi it is a bad idea to mix interfaces and objects. In this case you have two solutions:

1. declare MyInstance as IMyInterface and remove the call to Free.
2. inherit TMyClass from TInterfacedPersistent.

To clarify what is actually happening: Creating the TMyClass instance and assigning it to MyInstance will keep the reference count to 0. When you pass it to DoSomething a cast to IMyInterface takes place and the reference counter increases. When DoSomething ends the reference counter decreases to 0 and the instance is freed. The following call to Free will free an already freed instance.

Comment: That explains quite a lot, thank you. I had no idea that the interfaces in Delphi work that way. I guess I will probably do without them. However, can you explain what happened, when I used the const keyword? Does this avoid this implicit cast or the reference counting somehow?

Comment: The const keyword prohibits the reference counting for the interface parameter. Although that might work in this case it is not recommended to rely on it.

Answer (score 2):

DoSomething expect a IMyInterface

when you pass MyInstance , it's make a counter control, so when the method DoSomething finish, MyInstance has a counter decrement.

the TMyClass is a TInterfacedObject, so when the counter = 0, then Object will be freed, so you don't need to call MyInstance.Free;

you can do:

```
DoSomething(TMyClass.Create);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Object uses Reference Counting, to free it you must decrement the reference count. An alternative is to use what's called **CORBA** interfaces.

In FPC *object pascal mode* a **CORBA** interface is a pure interface which does not derivates from IUnknown (in opposite to **COM** interfaces). If you add the compiler directive:

```
{$INTERFACES CORBA}
```

then you'll be able to use the **.Free** method, just like with any other **TObject** instance. Note that the name can be confusing since CORBA is a full cross-language specification (IDL), but here corba just means *"not COM"*.

online reference:
http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refse44.html#x98-1080007.6